# http request not running on AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

First off, I admittedly don't know much about code in general, and JavaScript in particular. I'm guessing that there's probably something trivial wrong here, but I'm truly stumped.

I basically want this: http://tobuildsomething.com/2015/08/14/Amazon-Echo-Alexa-Tutorial-The-Definitive-Guide-to-Coding-an-Alexa-Skill/

However, unlike the New York City MTA, my local bus system does not publish a JSON feed. They do have a web site, however, that provides real-time arrival data. I heavily modified the example, but it still basically does the same thing: generate a URL based on the route, direction, and stop ID given to Alexa by the user, and returns the time of the next bus. Everything is working except the function that goes out and fetches the time from the web site.

*snip*

```
var url = 'http://rtabus.com/ada.aspx?r=' + route + '&d=' + whichWay() + '&s=' + whichStop();
console.log(url);
//Get the time for the next bus
//Scrape RTA web site for our data
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body); // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
    }
})
//var $ = cheerio.load(body);
//nextBusTime = $('.ada;nth-child(1)').text();
//console.log(nextBusTime);
```

*snip*

The code currently runs with no errors. However, while I see the URL being generated on the console, I do NOT see either of the `console.log` directives in the `request` block at all. Further, the function won't seem to write out to global variables, and if I uncomment the `var $` line, it errors out with "body not defined."

I'm sure I'm missing something trivial here, but I am stuck. Help?

Comment: Where is the code that calls the `request` function?

Comment: Isn't that it? That's the example from their github, and every example of a web scraper I've seen just has that function, followed by the cheerio.load bit.

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/04/web-scraping-with-nodejs/
^ just has the request() block, nothing that later refers to it.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js
^ Same here.

Comment: I guess I'm a little more rusty with JS than I thought I was. Have you put in break points before and after the request block to trace what is being computed? The Chrome JS console is great for that kind of thing: ctrl+shift+j

Comment: It seems like you would need an `else` block to do something `if (!error ...` is false, such as logging the error and such.